# Appending to a tripple quoted here-ish doc

Tags: python

I have a heredoc whose last line is rather long, so I'd love to put a line break in it for formatting well into the source, but... I am seeing some different behaviors depending on context. It makes sense, but it's also, imperfect. Is there some grouping operator I could use in both of the below cases to keep them equivalent in behavior? [Note you can't input it in the REPL easily, so that's a hint that I need some kind of grouping]

```
$ python -c 'print("""
> hello
> world
> """
> "Addendum: Long "
> "Line Here Is Broken Yet Continued."
> )'

hello
world
Addendum: Long Line Here Is Broken Yet Continued.
$ python -c 's="""
hello
world
"""
"Addendum: Long "
"Line Here Is Broken Yet Continued."
print(s)'

hello
world
```

That last one is taking the two extra strings as their own effectively No-op statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the grouping operator in the first example, it is the parenthesis.

```
$ python -c 's=("""
hello
world
"""
"Addendum: Long "
"Line Here Is Broken Yet Continued.")
print(s)'

hello
world
Addendum: Long Line Here Is Broken Yet Continued.
```

Comment: In Python 2 the parens to print() are optional. Because in Python 3 they are not as print() is a method, I didn't see that as grouping so much as calling. Thanks.